# Cannot read property 'getNotificationPermission_' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, gulp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using AngularJS with Gulp in my project. In localhost works fine, but when build it in production, it does not work and show the error below.

```
Unable to get permission to notify. TypeError: Cannot read property 'getNotificationPermission_' of undefined
    at vendor.js:100634
    at vendor.js:100634
    at Object.next (vendor.js:100634)
    at vendor.js:100634
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at n (vendor.js:100634)
    at a.requestPermission (vendor.js:100634)
    at vendor.js:100666
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set the firebase to the last version and the problem was gone.